# "Ok Google" i.e google assistant does not work for anyone but me

Tags: multi-user, voice-recognition, google-assistant

If I say "Ok Google", the assistant starts up just fine. However if my wife says it, nothing happens. She tried it several times, speaking loud and clear, but nothing happened. Is the assistant somehow expecting my voice only? Voice Match ist disabled, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Train her voice by going to

Settings → Google → Voice → Voice Match → OK Google Voice Model → Retrain Voice Model

on 7.1.2  for other versions  you may need to search in settings

Comment: This only seems to work for up to 3 people since you have to say "Ok Google" three times. What if you want it to work for more than three people?

Comment: Ok, I asked another question [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/188145/allow-google-assistant-to-be-voice-activated-by-more-than-three-people).