# Allow Google Assistant to be voice activated by more than three people

Tags: multi-user, voice-recognition, google-assistant

As a followup to [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/188041/ok-google-i-e-google-assistant-does-not-work-for-anyone-but-me) question: Is it possible to have the Google assistant be voice activated by more than 3 people?